# What are the Latin forms behind credit and debit?

Tags: etymology, money

The English terms credit and debit seem to come from the Latin verbs *credere* and *debere*.
However, it is not clear to me what forms of these verbs are behind these English words.
It could be that they used to be the third person singular forms *credit* and *debet* and the second one was changed by analogy.
Or perhaps they are abbreviated from *creditor* and *debitor*, both of which make sense in Latin.
Do we know what exact Latin forms of these verbs are behind these two financial terms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From French débit and crédit, which are from Latin debitum and creditum respectively.

Concerning the latter the OED writes:

> Etymology: < (i) Middle French credit (French crédit ) belief, faith,
>   trust (a1450), reputation, influence, esteem (c1470 or earlier), money
>   lent or borrowed with an agreement as to repayment (1481), trust or
>   confidence in a customer's ability and intention to pay at some future
>   time (1508 in a credit on credit), confidence that someone or
>   something inspires (1539),     and its etymon (ii) Italian credito
>   financial transaction in which payment is deferred (1353), position of
>   a creditor, right of a creditor (a1375), belief, fact of being
>   believed (14th cent.), reputation for solvency and probity in
>   financial dealings, ability to obtain money, etc., on this basis
>   (a1400), reputation, esteem (a1498), money placed at a person's
>   disposal in the books of a bank (mid 16th cent.) < classical Latin
>   crēditum loan or debt, in also post-classical Latin article of faith
>   (14th cent. in a British source), use as noun of neuter past
>   participle of crēdere to trust, to believe (see credit v.).

Comment: Thanks! It was somewhat asinine of me to not think of the possibility of the words coming through Romance languages.